# Having fun integral $\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos x \arctan(\cos x)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

Playing around with the inverse trigonometric function integration, I found a nice closed-form of the following integral

> $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos x \arctan(\cos x)\, dx=\frac{3\sqrt{2}-1}{4}\pi-\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\arctan\sqrt{2}$$

which numerically agrees with output of Wolfram Alpha. I am wondering, what is the nicest way (**or** the *most* complicated way) to obtain the given result. I would love to see how Mathematics SE users prove it. Any method is welcome. Thank you. (>‿◠)✌

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integrate by parts $$\int\cos x\arctan(\cos x)dx$$

$$=\arctan(\cos x)\int\cos x\ dx-\int\left(\frac{d[\arctan(\cos x)]}{dx}\int\cos x\ dx\right)dx$$

$$=\arctan(\cos x)\sin x-\int\left(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}\cdot\sin x\right)dx$$

Now, $$\int\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\int\frac{2-(1+\cos^2x)}{1+\cos^2x}dx$$

$$=2\int\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}-\int dx$$

$$=2\int\frac{\sec^2x\ dx}{2+\tan^2x}-x$$

Comment: Congrats for earning $100$K+ Mr. Lab (ô‿ô)

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts:
$$\int cos(x)arctan(cos(x))dx=sin(x)arctan(cos(x))+\int\frac{sin^2(x)}{1+cos^2(x)}dx$$

Rewrite:
$$\int cos(x)arctan(cos(x))dx=sin(x)arctan(cos(x))+\int\frac{2}{1+cos^2(x)}dx-x$$

To obtain this integral, we differentiate $arctan(\alpha tan(x))$, which results in $\frac{\alpha}{cos^2(x)+(\alpha sin(x))^2}$.

So we get:
$$\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}{cos^2(x)+\frac{1}{2}sin^2(x)}dx=arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}tan(x)\right)$$

Indefinite integral:
$$\int cos(x)arctan(cos(x))dx=sin(x)arctan(cos(x))+\sqrt{2}arctan(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}tan(x))-x$$

Plugging in the boundaries is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that I'm late but I found this other cool way to solve it:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos x\arctan(\cos x)dx &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos x\left[\arctan(y)\right|_{0}^{\cos x}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\cos x}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+y^2}dydx
\end{aligned}$$

Now, using Fubini's theorem we can interchange the order of integration by using this equivalent interval:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0\leq &x\leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}\\
0\leq &y\leq \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\cup
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0\leq &x\leq \arccos y\\
\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\leq &y\leq 1
\end{aligned}
\right\}
$$

Now we proceed:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\cos x}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+y^2}dydx &=\overbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}\dfrac{dy}{1+y^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos x dx}^{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\arctan(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})}+\int_{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}^1\int_0^{\arccos y}\dfrac{\cos x}{1+y^2}dydx \\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)+\int_{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}^1\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\dfrac{2\sqrt 2-1}{4}\pi+\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)-\sqrt 2\arctan(\sqrt 2)
\end{aligned}$$

The result numerically wise is the same, but I don't know how to manipulate it into the OP's form.

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$

Nevermind, using the indentity

$$\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2},$$

for $x=\sqrt{2}$ it is then trivial to get to the OP's form of result.